# problem adding css toolkit like tachyons to next.js project

Tags: css, next.js, tachyons-css

for training purpose I have created a ropo-Friend web app as a csr , now for the same purposes I am tring to recreate the same project using next.js this time as a great tool for ssr projects and I really have nightmares importing css addons like tachyons or even ./......css files that I created my self and attach it to the project 
it keeps showing me error message and as new next developer I can't solve this problem 
I am gonna attach my error message.

[image]
[image]